# how to print the text in value from curl

Tags: php, html

I have a cUrl request and Im having a problem when printing the value of input from the cUrl response

**here is the cUrl response**

[image: here is the cUrl response]

and I also tried postman to see the real HTML code and here it is

```
<input type=hidden name='decision'     value='REJECT' >
```

I wanted to echo what inside the `value=' '`

Comment: If the response contains HTML and you want to put it in a value attribute, you need to escape it using either [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) `value="<?= htmlentities($theResponse)?>"`.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson how do i echo it using PHP? edit: the HTML that i put is from the response and the `value='REJECT'` is what i want to echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a regex:

```
// $str is the cURL result, here setted by hand for test
$str = "<input type=hidden name='decision'     value='REJECT' >";
preg_match("/value='(.+)'/", $str, $matches);
// echo the string found or empty if it's not present `value='...'`
echo isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '';
```

With a `regex` you can search a portion of text by defining some rules.

In the above regex it will search the contents of the `value` attribute in the returned HTML.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Very well explained though <3

Comment: @JayJay - How can this be the answer when, according to your screen shot, the cURL response doesn't contain the input element at all?

Comment: can i do this `if(strpos($matches, 'REJECTED')){ echo 'rejected';}` so that if rejected is showed it will show the echo message. Or there is any code to do that ?

Comment: See my edit to handle the case when value isn't present.

Comment: @JayJay - `$matches` will be an array. `strpos()` is for strings so no, you can't use that. But you could use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: If you're just looking for an input with the value `REJECTED` (a static string), you could simply do: `if (strpos($theResponse, 'value="REJECTED"') !== false) { .... }`. You don't really need regex for that.